# Which Data Type does Firestore use for it's Timestamps?

Tags: angular, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm sure anyone who already knows will think this is an obvious question but I've already spent a lot of time searching the docs for this.

I would think you do something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export interface ChatMessage {
  message: string;
  dateSent: firebase.firestore.serverTimestamp();
}
```

Also, I've seen this in some places, but it doesn't work for me either...

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
```

I just get `Namespace 'firebase.firestore' has no exported member 'FieldValue'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured out what I was doing wrong! It should be this...

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

export interface ChatMessage {
  message: string;
  dateSent: firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
}
```

OR

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';

export interface ChatMessage {
  message: string;
  dateSent: firestore.FieldValue;
}
```

Then when I go to make a chat message, it will let me do this:

```
<ChatRoom>{
  newCount: newTotal,
  lastMessageDate: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
});
```

Comment: Use `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();` instead. See [docs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Timestamp).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your import statement to the following:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything :(